# Check for Per class misclassification

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I have split my data using the sklearn train_test_split function and i am using model.fit in keras to train.

Now during training it prints the training and validation statistics on to the terminal.

What i am interested is in though when it prints the validation stats like accuracy and loss, I want  to know a per class missclaffication number.Is that possible? I am training a binary classifier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get this information from [confusion matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html).

Comment: you can use [keras-metrics](https://pypi.org/project/keras-metrics/) for add **precision** and **recall** as validation metrics.